# I can't get the results of a variable

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to retrieve the `getChangePercent()` from a file named 'Classes' and display it in a file name 'StockTest', but it's not letting me.

I can declare the variable `ChangePercent` in the classes file at the top of the file, but I'm not allowed to do this.

I'm forced to declare `currentPrice` and `previousPrice` at the top as well in order for the program to work, which is NOT allowed.

```
 symbol = ''
 name = ''

 class Stock():
 def __init__(self, symbol = '', name = '', previousClosingPrice = 20.5, currentPrice = 20.35):
      self.__symbol = symbol
      self.__name = name
      self.__previousClosingPrice = previousClosingPrice
      self.__currentPrice = currentPrice

 def getName(self):
      return self.__name

 def getSymbol(self):
      return self.__symbol

 def getPreviousPrice(self):
      previousClosingPrice = 20.5
      previousClosingPrice = self.__previousClosingPrice
      return self.__previousClosingPrice

 def getCurrentPrice(self):
      currentPrice = 20.35
      currentPrice = self.__currentPrice
      return self.__currentPrice

 def getChangePercent(self):
      ChangePercent = round(1 - currentPrice / PreviousClosingPrice, 2)
      self.__ChangePercent = ChangePercent
      return self.__ChangePercent
```

Here is the StockTest code below.

```
from Classes import Stock

def main():

     stock1 = Stock('INTC', 'Intel Corporation', 20.5, 20.35) 
     print("The stock's symbol is", stock1.getSymbol())
     print("The stock's name is", stock1.getName())
     print("The stock was at", stock1.getPreviousPrice())
     print("The stock is now at", stock1.getCurrentPrice())
     print("The stock had a change of", stock1.getChangePercent())

main()
```

When I do declare the variables at the top of the 'Classes' file, I get displayed:

"The stock had a change of -0.01"

Keep in mind, I can't declare previousPrice and CurrentPrice like I did with 'symbol' and 'name' in the first set of code. I actually want the program to display:

"The stock had a change of -1%"

Please help!

Comment: Are you asking if your math is correct?

Comment: [Format String syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) has a percent type. ... `print('{:%2.2}'.format(stock1.getChangePercent())`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct percentage formatting `{0:.0%}` should do the trick.

```
print("The stock had a change of {0:.0%}".format(stock1.getChangePercent()))
#The stock had a change of 1%
```